# Markov Chains: regularity and detailed balance

Tags: markov-process

A Markov Chain with state transition matrix $A$ satisfies detailed balance with respect to distribution $\pi$ if for all $i,j$, we have $$\pi_iA_{i,j} = \pi_jA_{j,i}.$$

In such a case, we have $$\sum_i \pi_iA_{i,j} = \sum_j\pi_jA_{j,i} = \pi_j.$$

Isn't this enough to show that if $A$ satisfies the detail balance equations with respect to $\pi$, then $\pi$ is the stationary distribution for $A$?

The text I'm reading states the following theorem:

If a Markov chain $A$ is regular and satisfies detailed balance wrt $\pi$, then $\pi$ is a stationary distribution for $A$.

Why is regularity needed? Above we already showed that $\pi = A\pi$, which is the definition of a stationary distribution for $A$.

Edit:

As a silly example, if $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

then, for example, $\pi = [1,  0]$ satisfies the detailed balance equations and is a stationary distribution for the chain, even though the chain is not irreducible or regular.

Comment: Detailed balance only guarantees stationarity of $\pi$ when the Markov chain is irreducible. Else $\pi$ cannot be stationary.

Comment: Then why does the theorem use regularity instead of irreducibility?

Comment: $\pi=[1/2 \;\; 1/2]$ satisfies the detailed balance equations for the chain with $A=[0 \;\; 1; \;\; 1 \;\;  0]$, but it isn't a stationary distribution.

Comment: Why is it not a stationary distribution? The definition of a stationary distribution in my book is that $\pi = \pi A$, which is satisfied here. The definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions) is similar.

Comment: You have to be careful about whether "stationary distribution" means $\pi A=\pi$ and nothing else or whether "stationary distribution" means that $\pi A = \pi$ and $\pi$ is the limiting distribution for all initial states.  If the chain is regular and detailed balance is satisfied than $\pi$ is a limiting distribution for all initial states.  It seems likely that either you're misreading your sources or that the authors have been sloppy about this or that they simply included an unnecessary hypothesis in the theorem.

Comment: I think it must be the latter. The same thing with Wikipedia: _"A stationary distribution $\pi$ is a (row) vector, whose entries are non-negative and sum to 1, is unchanged by the operation of transition matrix P on it and so is defined by $\pi \mathbf{P} = \pi$."_ The two textbooks I have are similar; the definition of "stationary distribution" says nothing about what happens in the limit for arbitrary initial states.